# Como hacer que el programa elija aleatoriamente entre dos sudrutinas? vb

Tags: vba, vb

la cosa es esta, tengo una función que devuelve un numero del 0 al 10 de manera aleatoria luego de dar clic a una imagen, quiero que si el numero que devuelva resulta ser 5 entonces aparezcan dos imágenes en orden horizontal. Mi problema es que necesito que cada que salga el 5 se decida de manera aleatoria el par de imagenes que se mostrarán. Es decir, la imagen "A" y "B"  o el par de "C" y "D".
Intenté hacer una función para cada par, luego un generador aleatorio de numeros entre 1-2 para poner condicionar si sale 1 entonces mostrar el primer par de imagenes y si devuelve 2 mostrar el segundo par. Pero no funciona simplemente se queda pasmado.
Aquí esta lo que tengo de código
'''

```
     Private Sub Boton_Centro_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Boton_Centro.Click

   dado_yo() 'generador aleatorio de numeros del 1 al 10
            If dado_yo() = 5 Then
        Cambio_E() 'esta es la subrutina para que el par de imagenes se hagan visibles
    End If
End Sub
Public dcolor As Integer
Function orden_botones()
    Randomize()
    dcolor = Int((2 * Rnd()) + 1) 'generador de numeros aleatorios del 1 al 2
    Return dcolor
    
End Function
Sub Cambio_E()
    orden_botones()
    Boton_Centro.Enabled = False
    Do
        If orden_botones() = 1 Then Exit Do
        Paquete_1() 'cada paquete es una subrutina haciendo visible un par de imagenes
        If orden_botones() = 2 Then Exit Do
        Paquete_2()
    Loop
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que estás llamando varias veces a la función para evaluar lo que tu ves como una sola condición. Pero la rutina, cada vez que la llames, te va a devolver un valor aleatorio entre 1 y 2 y puede devolver el mismo valor varias veces consecutivas, tanto como puede no hacerlo.

Es decir, si `orden_botones()` una vez te devuelve `2`, nada garantiza que la próxima vez te devolverá `2` también, que es lo que tendría que suceder para que se ejecute exactamente una de las rutinas que llamas.

Lo que puedes hacer es invocar una sola vez a la función, almacenar el resultado de esta en una variable local y luego aplicar las condiciones sobre esa variable.

O bien, hacer un `if/else`, dado que solo hay dos posibilidades. La segunda sería así:

```
Sub Cambio_E()
    Boton_Centro.Enabled = False
    If orden_botones() = 1 Then 
      Paquete_1()
    Else 
      Paquete_2()
    End If 
End Sub
```

Como verás, he quitado también la primera llamada a `orden_botones()`, que me parece superflua, así como el ciclo, que no es parte de tu pregunta y no veo a qué viene. Si lo necesitas, simplemente añadelo de nuevo.

Si prefieres almacenar el valor en una variable, puedes hacerlo así:

```
Sub Cambio_E()
    Dim vOrden as Integer
    Boton_Centro.Enabled = False
    vOrden = orden_botones()
    If vOrden = 1 Then 
      Paquete_1()
    Elsif vOrden = 2 Then 
      Paquete_2()
    End If 
End Sub
```